# How do I find the total amount of nanoseconds from deltatime (datetime)?

Tags: python, datetime, seconds, nanotime

I am trying to get the current time in nanoseconds from the exact start of 01/01/2010

I thought about just multiplying the total seconds by 1e+9, however I don't  know how accurate that would be.

I've also tried to use `.total_nanoseconds()`, however that doesn't seem to work.

```
dateTimeObj = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)).total_seconds() 

print(dateTimeObj)
```

Comment: Multiplying the seconds is about as accurate as it gets with floating point numbers. Since the value of `total_seconds` is expressed as a float anyway, it's probably not 100% accurate to begin with. What kind of accuracy do you need over the span of 9 years…?

Comment: datetime only stores dates up to microseconds, not nanoseconds, and the only `.total_` method is `.total_seconds()`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new enough Python, you might be able to use `time.time_ns()` to accomplish this (by subtracting, I guess):

```
>>> import time
>>> time.time()
1560868060.8969848
>>> time.time_ns()
1560868065180866064
>>>
```

- [PEP 564](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0564/)
- [Related bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue31784)

I just tried it on the [Python shell in the browser at their website](https://www.python.org/shell/).

A couple bug reports regarding the module you are asking about, where this is not yet possible:

- [Add precision arguments](https://bugs.python.org/issue32522)
- [datetime has no nanoseconds](https://bugs.python.org/issue15443)

Comment: I assume there is a way to calculate the nanosecond for your date in 2010 using https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html